# Java echo server connection timeout issues

Tags: java, echo

I am implementing an echo server, in java, capable of handling multiple clients. Everything works locally, even when running mutiple clients. But when trying to run the client on another computer, we get

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

in the output. So my question is, what could be causing this? This is my first time working with servers, and I am a little lost.

The port is number 1100.

Here is are the classes for the server.

ThreadedEchoServer:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ThreadedEchoServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

if (args.length != 1) {
    System.err.println("Usage: java ThreadedEchoServer <port number>");
    System.exit(1);
}

    int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    boolean listening = true;

    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber)) { 
        while (listening) {

            new EchoThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();
                System.out.println("connected");
        } 
    }catch (IOException e) {

    System.err.println("Could not listen on port " + portNumber);
    System.exit(-1);
    }
}
}
```

EchoThread:

```
 import java.net.*; 
 import java.io.*;

public class EchoThread extends Thread {
private Socket socket = null;

public EchoThread(Socket socket) {
    super("EchoThread");
    this.socket = socket;
}

public void run() {

    try (
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
    ) {
        String inputLine, outputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(inputLine);
            outputLine = inputLine;
            if (outputLine.equals("Bye")) //If neccesassy to break using a command
                break;
        }

        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

And finally, the Echo Client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

Epublic class EchoClient {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.err.println(
            "Usage: java EchoClient <host name> <port number>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String hostName = args[0];
    int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    try (
        Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
        PrintWriter out =
            new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in =
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdIn =
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in))
    ) {
        String userInput;
        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(userInput);
            System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
            hostName);
        System.exit(1);
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: Any firewall present?

Comment: We have both turned off our firewalls.

Comment: but you are both in the same local network? your not connecting to him over the internet do you? For making this work over the internet try to combine it with a vpn client like hamachi

Comment: @user2504380 As in, we both had to be connected to the same network right? Like we were both connect to my school's student wifi in the same building

Comment: that doesnt mean you are in the same local network. Please make sure you are or just give hamchi a try anyway, or any other tunnel client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine for me with the Oracle Java and OpenJDK 1.7.0_55 with the client and server running one Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 7 (switched for client running on one, server running on the other).

There is certainly a network configuration problem (firewall, NAT).  You can try `telnet host port` (i.e. `telnet megadeth 1100`) from the remote client machine for another open port to confirm that you're getting the timeout.